# Faster Django Pagination App

Tags: mysql, django, paginator, django-pagination

We use django-paging, which is a bit old. One of the big issues is that the app performs a count on the queryset returned by each view, which is slow and doesn't provide us any value in our case.

I see that django-pagination has more downloads/repo-watchers.  I've also used the Django Digg Style paginator in the past.

Should we switch over to a new paginator app or just strip out the count MySQL query?

Thanks

Comment: how can you use digg-style pagination if you strip out the count?

Comment: Strip out the count from django-paging, not digg-style.  I suppose you always need to count, regardless of the underlying app. Probably the core of any pagination. My bad.